# Can I allow a user to sign a contract, and then based on that contract to make a transaction without approval?

Tags: web3js, ether, metamask, wallets, javascript

For example, let's say we have a sender and a receiver. A is the sender and B is the receiver.

For exampple I have a website. Using js, user A signs a contract, and by hitting the donate button on that website, it automaticly sends from user's A wallet, to user's B without confirmation pop-up from metamask in which user A has to confirm a transaction?

Comment: Unless you have A private key you won't be able to transfer funds without a wallet signing the transaction.

Comment: You need to do more research in the documentation of wallets